# Linq group by DateTime / intervals

Tags: c#, linq

I've the following query

```
 var x = from t in v
                    group t by t.Time.Year + "-" t.Time.Month + "-" + 
                      t.Time.Day + " " t.Time.Hour + ":" + t.Time.Minute into g
                    select new { Tag = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };
```

t.Time is a DateTime. The above smells a bit i.m.o. Are there any clean way
to group by intervals based on DateTimes ?

Edit: What I don't quite like about this is the string fiddling and producing a string. Ideally I'd like to produce a DateTime out of the group, not a string.

Comment: You can better replicate that formatting with `dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`. make sure you use upper case "H" for 24 hour, otherwise you'll be grouping AM and PM together...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems what I really wanted was

```
group t by
 new DateTime(t.Time.Year,t.Time.Month,t.Time.Day ,t.Time.Hour,t.Time.Minute,0) 
into g
```

None of the suggestiions involving Add/Subtract works for me, even if I also set the miliseconds to +.

dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") is a nice alternative to the strinc concatenation if I need a string though.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
group t by t.AddSeconds(60- t.Time.Seconds) // rounds to nearest minute
```

Comment: this will break for milisseconds values

Comment: Doesn't work. Even when I zero out the miliseconds  the query yields a ton of similar DateTimes - it doesn't group them.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
DateTime[] v = new DateTime[]
{
    new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 01, 01, 00, 100),
    new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 01, 01, 30, 200),
    new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 02, 01, 00, 300),
    new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 03, 01, 45, 400)
};

var x = from t in v
        //group t by t.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") into g
        group t by t.AddSeconds(-t.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % 60) into g
        select new { Tag = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };
```

**EDIT**: changed to `.AddSeconds`, per [@Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225371/linq-group-by-datetime-intervals/2225440#2225440) suggestion

Comment: It's atleast cleaner. I'd like to produce a DateTime though instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are 600,000,000 ticks in a minute, so you could do something like this in order to group by the nearest minute:

```
var x = from t in v
        group t by new DateTime(t.Time.Ticks - (t.Time.Ticks % 600000000)) into g
        select new { Tag = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = from t in v
group t by t.Time.Date.AddMinutes((Int32)t.Time.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) into g
   select new { Tag = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };
```